Defining a symbolic block matrix
I'm a total beginner in Mathematica and I have been struggling with defining the following symbolic matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Here, $\mathbb{1}_{m_i}$ and $\mathbb{0}_{m_i}$ stand for the unit and zero vectors of size $m_i$ respectively.
I first defined the integers $m_i$ using the Element function. Then, I defined each block $M_{ij}$ using the Array function. After that, I defined the unit and zero vectors using the ConstantArray and Transpose functions. But as I said, the tricky part is when I want to join everything together to form the matrix $M$.
Frankly, I'm not even sure of my choice of functions or my usage of them (sixteen Array usages, one subblock at a time!!! feel like there must be a shortcut I need to know about here).
can someone make my life easier by taking me for the complete beginner that I am and detailing a good method for me? Thank you in advance.

I do not know how big and complicated your definitions are. Could you as an experiment try M={{0,1,1m1t,1m2t,0m3t,0m4t}, {1,0,1m1t,0m2t,1m3t,0m4t}, {1m1,1m1,M11,M12,M13,M14},...} You write each of your 36 definitions in the right place to create your M Then you can test M to see if it works. You might be able to define some functions before you begin to initialize M and use those functions as you construct the elements of M Do you understand what I have described? In some cases Mathematica will use a vector as a column or as a row as needed if that helps.

Thank you @bill.

You can create a block matrix like:
The top right block is simply:
IdentityMatrix[2]

For simplicity I assume that all dimensions are 2. However, I give the dimensions explicitely, so that you can adapt them to your needs. Then the top right block is (note that a vector and its transposed is the same in MMA)
zeros = Array[0 &, #] & /@ {2, 2, 2, 2};
ones =   Array[1 &, #] & /@ {2, 2, 2, 2}; 
block1 = {{ones[[1]], ones[[2]], zeros[[3]], zeros[[4]]}, {ones[[1]], 
   zeros[[2]], ones[[3]], zeros[[4]]}}

Then the lower left block is the transpose of block1. For the lower right block I assume that you already defined the matrices mij:
mats = Array[Subscript[m, #1, #2] &, #] & /@ {{2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 
     2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 
     2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}};
block2 = ArrayReshape[mats, {4, 4}]

Then for the final block matrix:
mat = {{IdentityMatrix[2], block1}, {Transpose[block1], block2}} // 
   ArrayFlatten;
mat // MatrixForm



Thank you @Daniel Huber.

If you have access to the most recent version of Mathematica (14.1), you could use some new functions that support handling of symbolic matrices.
Here ist the brute force way to build the matrix M:
(mat = With[{onem1 = SymbolicOnesArray[{m1}], 
 onem2 = SymbolicOnesArray[{m2}], onem3 = SymbolicOnesArray[{m3}],
  zerom2 = SymbolicZerosArray[{m2}], 
 zerom3 = SymbolicZerosArray[{m3}], 
 zerom4 = SymbolicZerosArray[{m4}]}, {
 {0, 1, onem1, onem2, zerom3, zerom4},
 {1, 0, onem1, zerom2, onem3, zerom4},
 {onem1, onem1, MatrixSymbol["M11", {1, 1}], 
  MatrixSymbol["M12", {1, 2}], MatrixSymbol["M13", {1, 3}], 
  MatrixSymbol["M14", {1, 4}]},
 {onem2, zerom2, MatrixSymbol["M21", {2, 1}], 
  MatrixSymbol["M22", {2, 2}], MatrixSymbol["M23", {2, 3}], 
  MatrixSymbol["M24", {2, 4}]},
 {zerom3, onem3, MatrixSymbol["M31", {3, 1}], 
  MatrixSymbol["M32", {3, 2}], MatrixSymbol["M33", {3, 3}], 
  MatrixSymbol["M34", {3, 4}]},
 {zerom4, zerom4, MatrixSymbol["M41", {4, 1}], 
  MatrixSymbol["M42", {4, 2}], MatrixSymbol["M43", {4, 3}], 
  MatrixSymbol["M44", {4, 4}]}
 }]) // MatrixForm

Next line shows how to assign valus to the mi and to the matrix elements of the block matrices Mij
(mat = matrix2 /. {m1 -> 3, m2 -> 4, m3 -> 5, m4 -> 6, 
  MatrixSymbol["M12", {1, 2}] -> {{3, 4}}, 
  MatrixSymbol["M31", {3, 1}] -> {{1}, {3}, {6}}, 
  MatrixSymbol["M43", {4, 3}] -> {{a, 2, c}, {4, f, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {g, 11, 
  12}}}) // Normal // MatrixForm

If you want to dig deeper into Mathematica and get more familiar with the many functions that Mathematica offers, here is a more efficient way to build the matrix (more efficient = less typing and less error prone)
The matrix apparently consists of two parts: part1 is symmetric and contains the 0,1 and the 0-, 1-vectors.
(symMat = 
 With[{onem1 = SymbolicOnesArray[{m1}], 
 onem2 = SymbolicOnesArray[{m2}], onem3 = SymbolicOnesArray[{m3}],
  zerom2 = SymbolicZerosArray[{m2}], 
 zerom3 = SymbolicZerosArray[{m3}], 
 zerom4 = SymbolicZerosArray[{m4}]}, 
 SymmetrizedArray[{{1, 2} -> 1, {1, 3} -> onem1, {1, 4} -> 
   onem2, {1, 5} -> zerom3, {1, 6} -> zerom4, {2, 1} -> 
   1, {2, 3} -> onem1, {2, 4} -> zerom2, {2, 5} -> onem3, {2, 6} ->
    zerom4}, {6, 6}, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]]) // MatrixForm

Part2 holds the Mij Block matrices
symbolicMat[{n_, m_}] := 
MatrixSymbol[StringJoin["M", ToString[n], ToString[m]], {n, m}]
(mMat = SparseArray[{{n_, m_} :> symbolicMat[{n - 2, m - 2}] /; n > 2 && m 
> 2}, {6, 6}]) // MatrixForm

Adding these two parts results in the matrix M
(matrix2 = symMat + mMat) // MatrixForm


This answer says we can use ArrayFlatten to concat matrices.

If the below code does help you, please upvote my answer, thanks.
Clear["Global`*"];
m1 = 2;
m2 = 3;
m3 = 4;
m4 = 5;
(lastHalf1stRow = 
  Array[1 &, m1]~Join~Array[1 &, m2]~Join~Array[0 &, m3]~Join~
   Array[0 &, m4])
(lastHalf2ndRow = 
  Array[1 &, m1]~Join~Array[0 &, m2]~Join~Array[1 &, m3]~Join~
   Array[0 &, m4])
(firtHalf3rdRow = Array[{1, 1} &, m1])
(firtHalf4thRow = Array[{1, 0} &, m2])
(firtHalf5thRow = Array[{0, 1} &, m3])
(firtHalf6thRow = Array[{0, 0} &, m4])

Do[
 Unprotect[Evaluate[Symbol["mat" <> ToString[mi] <> ToString[mj]]]];
 Evaluate[Symbol["mat" <> ToString[mi] <> ToString[mj]]] = 
  RandomInteger[
   1, {ToExpression["m" <> ToString[mi]], 
    ToExpression["m" <> ToString[mj]]}];
 ,
 {mi, 1, 4}, {mj, 1, 4}]

(mats = Array[
     Symbol["mat" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]] &, {4, 4}] // 
    ArrayFlatten) // MatrixForm

(upperLeftPart = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}) // MatrixForm
(upperRightPart = 
   ArrayFlatten[{lastHalf1stRow, lastHalf2ndRow}]) // MatrixForm
(lowerLeftPart = 
   ArrayFlatten[{{firtHalf3rdRow}, {firtHalf4thRow}, \
{firtHalf5thRow}, {firtHalf6thRow}}]) // MatrixForm

{{upperLeftPart, upperRightPart}, {lowerLeftPart, mats}} // 
  ArrayFlatten // MatrixForm

